# how to create good htaccess

Tags: php, .htaccess, web

Excuse me , I just start to learn about .htaccess files . I'm trying to write it this way (my htaccess file)

```html
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
  RewriteEngine On
  RewriteBase /exmpl/vadik_route/
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
  RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
  ReqriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/$l
</IfModule>
```

and my index.php

```html
<?php 
echo $_SERVER['PATH_INFO'];

 ?>
```

but server through this error.

```html
Server error!

The server encountered an internal error and was unable to complete your request. Either the server is overloaded or there was an error in a CGI script.

If you think this is a server error, please contact the webmaster.

Error 500

localhost
Apache/2.4.17 (Win32) OpenSSL/1.0.2d PHP/5.6.15
```

How can I fix that

Comment: $l should be $1 and its Rewrite not Reqrite.

Comment: server error log? for example `/var/log/apache2/error.log` on debian. Also, does apache main configuration has `AllowOverride`?

Comment: Your htaccess is full of syntex errors.

Answer (score 1):

you can send the url by get method for example getme.php?url=/controller/model/
and you can take the url also divide by slash

```
 $_GET['url'] //it is going to show you the url.
```

lets look at the .htaccess and explain it.

```
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteBase / #dont forget to modify this part. it is explain which folder you project in
    RewriteEngine On Options All -Indexes RewriteBase /directoryname/ RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
    RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
    ###############  SEO     ##########################


#http://www.example.com/hello/booboo/ it takes the url  after .com/


       RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getme.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

now we sent all the url to getme.php and we can use it

getme.php

```
<?php

//we redirect to get in url=$1 so our get method name is url
$parca = explode("/", $_GET["url"]); //and we divided the url by slash .

echo $parca[0];//this is first part "/hello/
echo $parca[1];// and this is second part "/booboo/;
?>
```

Comment: thanks for detailed answers. Especially  @AhmetAtak your example is pretty clear . Sag ol gardas!

Comment: I have created .htaccess  and index.php file where I can set clear path for my folders   , but I have a folder login where situated all my login files and also language setting files . When I choose one of the language it's like this   ` form.php?lang=kr` . I couldn't write path for them in main index.php file  So should I create htaccess files for them too ? My goal is create web page with clear url . If it's possible plase let me know ?

Comment: Actually if you write echo $_GET["url"] in you index.php you will see something like this "form.php?lang=kr" however we divided address by slash as you know www.example.com/hello/booboo/ it means $parca[0]=hello, $parca[1]=booboo so you can  write www.example.com/language/kr/ first is language second is kr and you can say if ($parca[1]=='kr') include "your language file.php" if you don't want  to use this you should add "RewriteRule ^form.php?lang=(.*)$ getme.php?url=$1 [QSA,L] "  before this RewriteRule ^(.*)$ getme.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]   when you put this you will se url is going to be url=kr

Answer (score 1):

Change your .htaccess with this one:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On 

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f 
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d 

RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php?/$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

```html
<?php
  session_start();
  //Define Language file paths
  define("LANG_EN_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exmpl/sayt/multilang/en/');
  define("LANG_RU_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exmpl/sayt/multilang/ru/');
  define("LANG_KR_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exmpl/sayt/multilang/kr/');
  define("LANG_TR_PATH", $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '/exmpl/sayt/multilang/tr/');
 
if (isset($_GET['lang'])) 
{
     
    // GET request found
 
    if ($_GET['lang'] == 'ru') 
    {
      include LANG_RU_PATH . 'ru.php';
      $_SESSION['lang'] = 'ru';
    }  
    
    else if ($_GET['lang']=='en') {
      include LANG_EN_PATH .'en.php';
      $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
    }
    
    else if ($_GET['lang']=='tr') {
      include LANG_TR_PATH .'tr.php';
      $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
    }

    else
    {
    include LANG_KR_PATH . 'kr.php';
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'kr';
    }

}   
     
     //translate for russian
      else if (isset($_SESSION['lang'])) 
      {
 
    if ($_SESSION['lang'] == 'ru') 
          {
           include LANG_RU_PATH . 'ru.php';
          } 
 //translate for kyrg 
    else if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'en') 
        {
          include LANG_KR_PATH . 'en.php';
          $_SESSION['lang'] = 'en';
        }
        
   // translate for turkish
    if($_SESSION['lang'] == 'tr') 
        {
          include LANG_TR_PATH . 'tr.php';
          $_SESSION['lang'] = 'tr';
        }

     else {
          include LANG_KR_PATH . 'kr.php';
          }
     
                   
     } 
     
     
    
    else 
    {
     
    include LANG_KR_PATH . 'kr.php';
    $_SESSION['lang'] = 'kr';
  }

?>
```

could you write path for this , as clear url